# using libpcap on android

Tags: android, c++, c, libpcap

I want use libpcap on android studio , but I don't know how I can use this library.
I want to cerate a frame and send to network on layer of 2 on the network , for creating frame should I use libpcap? can't I use Java Code?
And then I want know that how many devices connect to the access point.
How can I add thsi library to android studio?
How can I use this library , I am beginer to this kind of project.
Is there any complete tutorial about this?
Is there any one can help me , step by step?
This is very very important for me and I neet to our help.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you research and try anything so far? Please share the results.

Comment: Yed I did , but all of my result doesn't good work on android sutiod , some people suggestion to me to use jnetpcap but unfortunately I didn't know how i can use this library , I can call all the calsses and mothods after import org.jnetpcap but I don't know how i can use this class , Do you know Dear friend?

Comment: I found some sample about jnetpcap but it trhows ExceptionInInitializerError on android studio, when I use JPacket class , Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jnetpcap. I believe you should make another question and ask for the specific error with showing your code. I'm the owner of pcap4j so I can help you if you face problems in use of pcap4j, though. (But pcap4j doesn't support android and IEEE802.11 well yet, so it might not be enough.)